# php mysql multiple field search empty fields

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');
    $conditions = array();
    foreach($fields as $field){
        if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {
            $conditions[] = "`".$field."` like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]) . "%'";
        }
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customer ";
    if(count($conditions) > 0) {
        $query .= "WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $conditions); 
    }
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    $say = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($say == 0) {
        echo "<tr>no result.</tr>";
        } else {

echo '...';     
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  ...

  }}
} ?>
```

Why doesn't this code checking empty fields? It returns results that has empty field even form submits empty.

Comment: Are the fields empty or are they NULL?

Comment: remove % & give LIKE '' (blank)

Comment: `mysql_*()` API are deprecated. Use either the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension instead. [Deprecated mysql_*()](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: @milesh can you show us what `$query` is holding before this `$result = mysql_query($query);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customer ";
if(count($conditions) > 0) {
$query .= "WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $conditions); 
}
```

When form is submitted empty ($conditions=0) it returns all table (select * from customer).

Added an else condition and fixed. Thanks for print query advices.

Answer (score 1):

The only improvement I think of is `trim()`:

```
if(isset($_POST[$field]) && trim($_POST[$field]) != '') {
```

however, I am sure it is not the issue.
Have you ever thought of **printing the resulting query out**?
Look, you're writing a program to create some string (SQL query). But for some reason never interested in this program's direct result, judging it by some indirect results. May be it's data/query logic makes such results, but the query itself is okay?

if the query is still wrong - continue debugging.
Echo everything involved - print variables, condition results, intermediate results in the loop - and look for inconsistencies

Answer (score -1):

For checking something is empty or not. You can use empty() method.

Check this:

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

isset() only check whether that object/variable is set or not. For more details check this

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: There is that control.

`if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '')`

Comment: have you tried this also `if(isset($POST[$field]) && !empty($_POST[$field]))`

Comment: Yes. Still returns results.

Comment: then you to have check what is actually you are getting in `$_POST[$field]` when it is empty.. check it with `var_dump($_POST[$field])` it will tell you the length also what are you getting..